# Going through all items in list

Tags: list, haskell

Result of this function:

```
list = [x*x | x <- [0..100]]    
res = id
    . filter (\(x,y,sum) -> sum > 9)
    . takeWhile (\(x,y,sum) -> sum < 100)
    . nub
    $ [(x, y, (sqrt (x) + sqrt (y))) | x <- list, y <- list]
```

is [(0, 100, 10), (0, 121, 11 ... (0, 9801 ,99)].
How can I make it work with other items in x's list?

Comment: Now it work with x = 0 and y = 0..99, I want it to print result when x = 0..99 and y = 0..99

Comment: Only the outermost pair of round brackets in the last line is required. `id` is not necessary as well because it is, well, the identity function. Also, I'm pretty sure `nub` is unnecessary as well.

Comment: convert the `takeWhile` into a `filter`.

Comment: if `a == sqrt(b)`, doesn't it mean that `a*a == b`? if `n == sqrt(x*x)`, doesn't it mean that `n == x`? if `p + q > 9`, doesn't it mean that `q > 9 - p`? if `p + q < 100`, doesn't it mean that `q < 100 - p`?

Comment: using filter instead of takeWhile fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 3):

A `takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` is a function that - like the name says - takes elements while the condtions holds. From the moment one such element fails, then the rest of the list is not emitted anymore, regardless whether it yields valueable data or not.

Since your `list` is however finite, and you are interested in all configurations, you do not have to use `takeWhile` here, you can use `filter`, so:

```
res = id
    . filter (\(x,y,sum) -> sum > 9)
    . filter (\(x,y,sum) -> sum < 100)
    . nub
    $ [(x, y, (sqrt (x) + sqrt (y))) | x <- list, y <- list]
```

Now we have fixed this. But the code still has some redundant and inelegant aspects.

We better avoid calculating the square root, by modifying `list` to emit squares together with the original value. Furthermore we can simply make it an infinite list, which is usally better if we want to reuse it in other parts of the code:

```
squares = [ (x, x*x) | x <- [0..]]
```

Next we thus will take values for as long as the value square root is less than 100:

```
   where sq100 = takeWhile (\(r,_) -> r < 100) squares
```

Now we can use list comprehension that takes square roots and squares of the two lists and calculate the sum of the square roots, such that the sum is greater than 9 and less than 100. We can thus write:

```
res = [ (x,y,sqq) | (sqx,x) <- sq100, (sqy,y) <- sq100, x <= y,
                    let sqq = sqx+sqy, sqq > 9, sqq < 100 ]
     where sq100 = takeWhile (\(r,_) -> r < 100) squares
```

Here we thus take an `x` and square root `sqx` of `x`, we take an `y` and square root `sqy` of `y`, then we constraint `x <= y` to remove duplicates, calculate the sum of the square roots `sqq = sqx+sqy` and finally we check whether that sum if greater than 9 and less than 100.

This produces 2520 results.

Answer (score 2):

The `takeWhile` is the culprit because the sum will be > 100 at some point, and then the list gets cut off.